# jquery select the corresponding column in a table

Tags: jquery

I have the following table mark up

```
<table>
 <tr>
  <td>
   <checkbox />
  </td>
  <td id="delete">

  </td>  
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>
   <checkbox />
  </td>
  <td id="delete">

  </td>  
 </tr>
</table>
```

What I want to achieve is -
When a user clicks a checkbox in one of the columns, I want to add a class to the column (id of delete) in the same row. How can I achieve this? The column may not be in the column beside the checkbox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly you should use `class` of delete as `id` attributes must be unique, then something like this should work:

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function() {
    $(this).closest('td').siblings('.delete').addClass('foo');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

**[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/ilisom/1/edit)**

You cannot have multiple ID in one page!!!

```
$('table :checkbox').change(function(){
  $(this).closest('tr').find('.delete').addClass('something');
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/closest/
http://api.jquery.com/find/
http://api.jquery.com/addclass/

That was to answer directly your question.
But talking about **checkboxes** I suppose you want this toggle finctionality:

```
$('table :checkbox').change(function(){
  $(this).closest('tr').find('.delete').toggleClass('something');
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/ilisom/2/edit)**

> The column may not be in the column beside the checkbox.

The `.find()` method is the fella that will will do the job searching for a `.delete` inside the children of a `.closest()` element.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function() {
   $(this).closest('td').siblings('.delete').toggleClass('ToBeAddedClass');
});
```

This will toggle the class when checkbox changes.

- `when checked` add a class.
- `when unchecked` remove the added class.

## note:

use `delete` as a `css class name` instead of `id named delete`